# FUSE filesystem -> bash: ./configure: Brak dostępu

Tags: bash, fuse

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/ 
When i try to configure, bash send me error.

```
./configure
bash: ./configure: Brak dostępu
```

It's mean access denied. 
I try to do this with sudo.

How to install FUSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions on `./configure` should be `rwxr-xr-x` or `r-xr-xr-x`. Use:

```
chmod a+x configure
```